# How to search a word in a 2d string array in C programming

Tags: c, search, arrays

How to search for the whole word in an 2d array of strings.
This code outputs me only the first letter of the word I enter.

can anyone help me with this ?

And how is that index passed in a function only the index I find form this search .

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#define PEOPLE 4
#define LEN_NAME 30

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    char found_name;
    char name[PEOPLE][LEN_NAME]= {"John Lucas","Armanod Jonas",
                                "Jack Richard","Donovan Truck"};

    printf("What name do you want to search?\n>");
    scanf("\n%s", &found_name);
    for (i = 0 ; i < PEOPLE; i ++)
    {
        if (strchr(name[i], found_name ) != NULL)
        {
            printf( "Found %c in position %d,%s\n", found_name, i+1, name[i]);
            printf( " index of player is %d.\n",i +1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make found_name a char array, not char. Also, you need to search using strstr (search for string), not strchr (search for single character).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#define PEOPLE 4
#define LEN_NAME 30
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char found_name[LEN_NAME];
    char name[PEOPLE][LEN_NAME] = { "John Lucas", "Armanod Jonas",
    "Jack Richard", "Donovan Truck"
    };

    printf("What name do you want to search?\n>");
    scanf("%29s", found_name);
    for (i = 0; i < PEOPLE; i++) {
    if (strstr(name[i], found_name) != NULL) {
        printf("Found %c in position %d,%s\n", found_name, i + 1,
           name[i]);
        printf(" index of player is %d.\n", i + 1);
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That was it buddy, Thank you very much .
Now , do you know how to pass only this index into a function:

like i have some values:

`score [PEOPLE]={ 23,12,45,12};`
and i create a function where i find the smallest, and then I want to display only the score for this index i found ( from search ) and the position of that person.

do you have any idea anything would help me 
thank you , appreciate it

Comment: `int smallest(int a[], int n) { int i,m=a[0]; for(i=1; i<n; i++) if(a[i]<m) m=a[i]; return m; }`

Answer (score 0):

Found_name is only a character when it should be a char *with the correct amount of space.  So if you type in "Find this string", how could you store that string into a 1 byte location?